# Right permissions to WordPress directory

Tags: directory, linux

Knowing that not all files and folders have the same permissions, What are the right permissions in order to avoid hacker attacks and to allow the sites updates and upgrades?

My site is installed on Linux Debian 7

**Note.** My mother language is Spanish, so I apologize if my question is not fully understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard file/folder permission for WordPress:

`755` for folders

`644` for files

Comment: Do you mean `chmod 755 -R /var/www/mySite` and `chmod 644 -R /var/www/mySite/*`

Comment: Not sure about your command. I normally use `find /var/www/mySite/ -type f -print -exec chmod 644 {} \;` and `find /var/www/mySite/ -type d -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;` Let me know if it helps. I'll include it to answer.

Answer (score 0):

755 for root directory 775 for uploads and wp-content folder